# My Android App give me SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, socket-timeout-exception

Recently I am working on an android app, but there is something working with my APIs
my phone and my laptop at the same wifi,
here is the scenario
I send the request to API from the postman then go to my phone and sent the same request it gives me the next message

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.mysite.com/23.xxx.xxx.xx (port 443) from /192.xxx.x.x (port 58280) after 10000ms`

But if I request the same API from my android app and hit the same API from Postman it works fine

I have searched a lot but without any solutions .. have anyone faced the same thing before in android

Comment: How are you invoking this API in your app and how long does it take to get a response via postman?

Comment: @Jameido I am using retrofit in my android app , it tasks range from 400 ms to 1300 ms

Comment: Can you show more details about the implementation and how are you invoking the api via postman?

Comment: You can use to this case port forwarding like use in local host machine ngrok tools, you api will expose all place mobile, on internet